# wireshark udp contains string

Tags: filter, udp, substring, wireshark

I'm trying to use WireShark to find UDP packets with a specific substring. I tried using a filter "udp and data.text contains SUBSTRING", but that returns nothing, even if SUBSTRING shows in the packet dump on the bottom window. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the expression `udp contains <hex>` where `<hex>` is a hex string like e1b0adde.